# Proof of vector multiplication and row equivalent problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let there is a matrix $A$ and a vector $x$.

Let's say $Ax=0$.

Does that mean every single matrix which is row equivalent with matrix $A$ becomes zero when multiplied by vector $x$? And does that mean if a matrix is zero when multiplied by vector $x$, that matrix is row equivalent with matrix $A$?

How can I prove these?

Comment: the first and the second questions are actually same, $p \implies q$ is same as $\neg q \implies \neg p$

Comment: thanks for the comment. changed description to q->p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  We know that if $A x=\mathbf{0}$ for a $n \times n$ matrix $A$, then $B A x=\mathbf{0}$ for all $n \times n$ matrices $B$.  Elementary row operations can be performed by matrix multiplication by [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrices).  Thus, by choosing $B$ as the product of elementary matrices, we find that any matrix $R$ row equivalent to $A$ satisfies $R x=\mathbf{0}$ too.

The converse is not true, with the counterexample:
$$
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}^{\text{call this $S$}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}^{\text{call this $T$}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $S$ and $T$ are not row equivalent.